# Predict Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found in R

Tags: r, predict

I tried to predict several models using a previous function, but but I'm getting "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'var.1' not found". That's is weird because var.1 is not in the dataframe. The code is:

```
library(randomForest)
library(ada)
library(class)
library(e1071)
library(rpart)
library(car)
library(nnet)
library(kknn)

Consenso <- function(DF,VAR.DEP){ #entries are a dataframe and a dependent var
N1 <- sample(DF,dim(DF)[1],replace=TRUE)
N2 <- sample(DF,dim(DF)[1],replace=TRUE)
N3 <- sample(DF,dim(DF)[1],replace=TRUE)
N4 <- sample(DF,dim(DF)[1],replace=TRUE)
N5 <- sample(DF,dim(DF)[1],replace=TRUE)
mod.kknn <- train.kknn(VAR.DEP ~.,data=N1,kmax=trunc(sqrt(dim(DF)[1])))
mod.net <- nnet(VAR.DEP ~ ., data = N2, size = 10, rang = 0.1, 
                     decay = 5e-04, maxit = 400, trace = FALSE, MaxNWts  = 20000)
mod.tree <- rpart(VAR.DEP ~ ., data = N3)
mod.sv <- svm(VAR.DEP ~ ., data = N4, kernel = "linear")
mod.rf <-randomForest(VAR.DEP ~.,data= N5,ntree=400)
lista.mod <-   list("Modelo.kknn"=mod.kknn,"Modelo.Redes"=mod.net,"Modelo.Arboles"=mod.tree,"Modelo.SV"=mod.sv,"Modelo.RF"=mod.rf)
return(lista.mod)
}
#Using the function
pbiris <- Consenso(iris,iris$Species)
#Make a prediction
predict(pbiris$Modelo.kknn,iris)
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sepal.Width.1' not found
#Var Sepal.Width.1 is not in the dataframe.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell for sure given your code is not exactly minimally reproducible, but almost certainly the problem is from:

```
sample(DF, dim(DF)[1], rep=T)
```

The problem is you are sampling the columns of the data frame, not the rows.  Consider:

```
DF <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8)
sample(DF, dim(DF)[1], rep=T)
```

Produces:

```
  b b.1 b.2 a
1 5   5   5 1
2 6   6   6 2
3 7   7   7 3
4 8   8   8 4
```

Since our data frame has fewer columns than rows, if you try to sample columns as many times as there are rows it will re-sample the same columns several times.  In our test we re-sampled column `b` three times, so we get `b`, `b.1`, and `b.2`.  Of course, your original data frame does not have the extra columns so your `predict` call fails.

Remember, `data.frame` objects are lists, so you just sampled the elements of the list.  To sample rows:

```
DF[sample(nrow(DF)), ]
```